# git add with additional gitignore by argument

Tags: git

Due to I am not commit ***bin** each time

I need **git add** or **git diff**, **git stats** with additional ignore file patten from .gitignore.

is any such options for git like as

> git status --ignore "*bin"

Answer (score 1):

1. Create *.gitignore* file (that is exact name of the file) in repository. Add and commit it.
2. Add there "bin/" row (in other words - add there relative path to folder to ignore. Don't forget to put / at the end - so it will ignore folder's content) - so changes in this folder will be not tracked.
3. If you already commited files in bin folder, then you need to check this thread [How do I make Git forget about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-do-i-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) to stop them tracking.